# How to drop the 2nd column of row index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

Here is the input:

```
df_row = df_row.filter(['identifier','link', 'likes_count','company'])
df_row = df_row.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
index        identifier                               link       likes_count    company
0   0   2293068067321995905 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_SnUIOhOKB 7609    Ralph Lauren
1   1   2293002309485390353 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_SYXOeBuoR 6943    Ralph Lauren
2   2   2292961870690462497 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_SPKw6BSsh 10328   Ralph Lauren
3   3   2292512316069378197 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_Qo84ihfiV 11446   Ralph Lauren
4   4   2292462538514040606 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_QdohlBQce 11500   Ralph Lauren
... ... ... ... ... ...
1995    995 1637123893923027648 https://www.instagram.com/p/Ba4O4H2lhrA 56939   Tommy Hilfiger
1996    996 1637053551812693979 https://www.instagram.com/p/Ba3-4gqFk_b 40843   Tommy Hilfiger
1997    997 1636400741496588158 https://www.instagram.com/p/Ba1qc3rFwd- 59361   Tommy Hilfiger
1998    998 1636290694309417692 https://www.instagram.com/p/Ba1RbePlxLc 40936   Tommy Hilfiger
1999    999 1635675075306271515 https://www.instagram.com/p/BazFdCXlzMb 34485   Tommy Hilfiger
```

How to drop the 2nd column of index?
Solved.

Comment: Do not do the `reset_index()`

Comment: without the reset index, there will be double index, because Ralph Lauren has 1000 entries (from 0 to 999) and so does Tommy Hilfiger (from 0 to 999). @hadik

Comment: can you try `reset_index(drop=True)` then? This will make sure old index is not added as a column to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `reset_index(drop=True)`

This will make sure old index is not added as a column to the dataframe.

[Read more on the `reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `reset_index`, it includes the previous index as a column in the dataframe. It can be avoided by giving `drop = True`

```py
df_row = df_row.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.